# How can I supply my own version while building electron

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

Is there any way I can supply a dynamic version no during the build of electron client.I am currently using electron builder for the same .My build script looks like below.

```
    "dist": "electron-builder",
```

I came across a post where it seems it was possible but not sure how to use it .He has mentioned something like below

```
"scripts": {
     "dist": "build --em.mode=prod --em.version=yourversion" 
}
```

Any clue on this would be helpful .

Comment: Maybe you could use [npm version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) to come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The "version" key of package.json can be used for this purpose.
Then the value can be accessed like this:

```
const { remote } = require("electron");

const applicationVersion = remote.app.getVersion();
```